# How can i solve if condintion with join. How I take use if with string join

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, list-comparison

```
job = ''.join([i for i in job if not i.isdigit()])
```

Error text:

> job = ''.join([i for i in job if not i.isdigit()])
> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: It looks like the `job` variable is a type of `float`. Can you check by doing `print(type(job))`. Can you share a bit more of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `isdigit` is a string method, I assume you are trying to iterate over the characters in a string and remove all digits. If this is the case, you can cast `job` to be a string in the list comprehension:

```
job = ''.join([i for i in str(job) if not i.isdigit()])
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. you helped fix the my error :)

Answer (score 0):

The operative part here is 'in job'.

If you run `print(job)` before the line in question, you'll see that the job variable is a floating-point number, not something iterable like a list or set.

Make sure job is iterable. If the error isn't resolved, it would be helpful if you pasted the output of `print(job)` with the question.

Comment: I get <b>nan</b> result when I want to print job